# SVG Polygon out of local JSON File in Angular

Tags: html, json, angular, svg

I'm working on an Angular 7 project where i'm building the game of Risk.
To create the world map I made a local JSON File that I call for in my Angular code.

The JSON looks like this:

```
["bord", {
    "continent": [
        {
        "land": [
            {
                "naam":["Ukraine"],
                "points": [[
                    [1561,236],
                    [1561,239],
```

I made a BordService where I try and acces the JSON file locally using HTTPClient like:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Landen } from '../model/landen';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class BordService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 

  }

  getJSON(): Observable <Landen> {

       return this.http.get<Landen>('./assets/json/landen.json');
  }

}
```

I subscribe to it in component like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.BordService.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
      this.Land = data["Landen"];
    })
```

In my HTML I call for the values defined in the JSON as follows:

```
<svg>
  <polygon *ngFor="let Land of Landen" 
  id={{Landen.continent }}
  class= {{Landen.naam }}
  points={{ Landen.points }}/>

</svg>
```

But I still can't seem to get a map on my screen..

Any and all help would be appreciated!!

Comment: update your question on how your subscribing the request in your component

Comment: @Lucho like this?

Comment: Yes, but add aswell the component on how you are subscribing getJSON

Comment: @Lucho sorry didn't read correctly..

Comment: You need to connect the data you're getting back to the component. `console.log(data)` does not do that. You'd need to do something like `this.Landen = data;`.

Comment: Your question is not clear on what exactly is not working for you, can you be more precise? If it is on how to populate the component from requests I suggest you go through the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data) tutorial in order to get a grasp on how Angular works

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you  missed that indeed! unfortunatly still no map visible..

Comment: @Lucho to be more clear: de JSON holds countries with points on them to create an svg world map. I want to see that world map but only see a blank page right now.

Comment: How does the data-structure/interface for Landen look like?

Comment: @Lucho simple like this: export class Landen{
    continent: string;
    land: string;
    naam: String;
    points: string;
}

Comment: `{{ Landen.points }}` by itself won't format the coordinates in the correct format for that attribute.  I believe you'll need to do something like `{{ Landen.points.join(',') }}`